# Can I use angular pwa for angular 7?

Tags: angular, angular-pwa

I am trying to add service workers to my Angular 7 application. I read on the angular documentation that is should be the last angular version for pwa to work, but i want to keep 7.2.3. When I am making ng add @angular/pwa --project -name- is added to package, but is not creating manifest and what is saying in angular documentation. Is there any way to manage this or I neeed to update my cli to make it work? (https://angular.io/guide/service-worker-intro)

This warning is showing me after the install:
Invalid rule result: Instance of class Promise.

Comment: yes you can definetly use service worker i have used in my angular 8 app

Comment: ok, so it does not need to be the latest version of angular, right? and what version of pwa did you used?

Comment: "@angular/animations": "^8.2.2",
    "@angular/common": "~8.2.2",
    "@angular/compiler": "~8.2.2",
    "@angular/core": "~8.2.2",
    "@angular/forms": "~8.2.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~8.2.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~8.2.2",
    "@angular/pwa": "^0.802.1",
    "@angular/router": "~8.2.2",
    "@angular/service-worker": "~8.2.2",

Comment: ng g service-worker than ng add pwa(worked this way), but manifest.json is not generated and nor the pictures in assets, but I think I can configure manually that manifest.json

Comment: or if you want to just test just try to make one simple blank application with service worker only

Comment: ok, thank you! finally working on this one :)